# How to use I18n and Json Schema in Form-generator at run-time?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, jsonschema, vue-i18n

I have a form which will be created by a formGenerator based on a json-schema which is fetched from server. I want to translate values based on languages. I dont know how should i interpret it at run time using i18n to handle this.

for example, the server sends a Json-schema like below, and we should make a form from it, e.g.:

```
{
  "instance": {
    "specification": {
      "label": "",
      "title": ""
    }
}
```

and if we pass it to the our simple form generator, it simply generates two empty tag like below:

I have to use translate files(like en.json in below) to fill fetched json-schema and then pass it to the form Generator.

```
  {
    "instance":{
        "specification":{
            "label":"this is label",
            "title":"this is title"
        }
    }
}
```

I know if those two span where in the template i could use $t("instance.specification.label") and  $t("instance.specification.label") like below, to use translate files in i18n to make it work:

```
<span>{{$t(instance.specification.label)}}</span>

<span>{{$t(instance.specification.title)}}</span>
```

But i wonder how should i do this in this case which is a dynamic json schema?

Comment: Including cryptic keys in your JSON schema makes it hardly usable in it itself. How about expecting the target language to be provided to the server, which then returns the schema with properly translated labels and descriptions?

Comment: This is project expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to use i18n for this purpose, so i made a library for this use case for anyone has same problem as me.  here is the library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-translator-for-json-templates

**update**

To use this package, you can use mustache templating(for more, see the link) in your template-file like below:

```
//template.json
{
      "platformType": "{{specification.platformType}}",
      "ownershipMode": "COBO",
      "version": 1,
      "description": "{{specification.description}}",
      "label": "{{specification.label}}"
}
```

And you also have to prepare the language file for it, for example:

```
//en_lang.json
 {"specification": {
        "platformType": "Android",
        "description": "Command Schema For 'Company Owned/Business Only'",
        "label": "COBO3"
      }
 }
```

And finally you can use the liberary like below example:

```
import i18nTranslatorForJsonTemplates from "i18n-translator-for-json-templates";
const result = i18nTranslatorForJsonTemplates(en_lang, template);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
/*output
 {                                                                       
   "platformType": "Android",                                            
   "ownershipMode": "COBO",                                              
   "version": 1,                                                         
   "description": "Command Schema For 'Company Owned/Business Only'",    
   "label": "COBO3"                                                      
 }                                                                       
*/
```